# Memcached returning NULL intermittently

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have tried both EnyimMemcachedCore and IMemoryCache methods but in both cases, values are getting null **sometimes** not always. and getting below error in both.

```
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's') at
```

Below is my code(I tried both EnyimMemcachedCore and IMemoryCache)

```
private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
public static CacheService _cacheMemory = new();

_cacheMemory.AddCacheData("flightData_" + _uid, FlightMainData, 1800);
_memoryCache.Set("flightData_1" + _uid, FlightMainData.Medium, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30));
```

I am retrieving like below,

```
var resultsData = _cacheMemory.GetCacheData("flightData_" + _uid);
var resultsData1 = _memoryCache.Get<string>("flightData_1" + _uid);
```

FYI: I am storing a little big-size data to cache and also the traffic of my site is very high. Is this issue because of the heavy traffic I am getting or anything else? Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you pinpoint which method call is throwing that exception? It isn't clear from your question if it is when you add or set data, or when you retrieve it.

Comment: the issue is when retrieving the data

Comment: So what you're saying is that either `resultsData` or `resultsData1` sometimes end up being `null`? And you're 100% sure that you previously added those items to the cache?

Comment: yes you're correct